# SQL - If not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I have a table in DB where some records exist.

[image: table]

When I add a new record I need to check by column "Name" if the record exists in DB. If such a record does not exist - then add it, if exists - then update. I'm trying like this:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

DECLARE @daily nvarchar = 'DailySummaryEmailProcessor'


IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                    FROM   [dbo].Crons
                    WHERE   name = @daily) 
            BEGIN                    
                   INSERT INTO [dbo].Crons (CronJobID, Name, Description)
                                    VALUES()                         
            END

ELSE
             BEGIN 
                   UPDATE  [dbo].Crons
                   SET
                   WHERE
             END
```

Comment: And your problem is? Leave the tag for the actual database you are using (MySQL isn't SQL Server).

Comment: Is this the right way to implement this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server..

Answer (score 2):

MERGE should fit your requirements [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
MERGE Crons AS target  
USING (SELECT @Name) AS source (Name)  
ON (target.Name = source.Name)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.Name = source.Name 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT INTO Crons (Name) VALUES (source.Name)
OUTPUT $action, deleted.Name, inserted.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is you never declare the size of the variable @dialy

try this and see what do you get

```
DECLARE @daily nvarchar = 'DailySummaryEmailProcessor'
SELECT @daily
```

Looks like you need to do INSERT .. UPDATE.. check out `MERGE` statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

EDIT:

Oh.. you have `MySQL` there in the tag. My answer is specifically on `SQL Server`.

Comment: According to the code sample he has given, He is using SQL Server. :-)